# How to use ViewModel in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I need to save the data downloaded from the server when the screen is rotated. I'm trying to do this using the ViewModel. But I get typeMismach here `model.getJokes().observe(this, object : Observer<List<Jokes>>()`

```
class ItemsFragment : Fragment() {

var type: String? = ""
private var api: Api? = null
var adapter = ItemsAdapter()
private var jokes: List<Jokes> = ArrayList()
private var jokesCount: Int? = null
private var items: Result? = null
private var itemsCount: ResultCount? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val args = arguments
    type = args?.getString(KEY_TYPE)

    api = (activity?.application as App).api

    val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(JokesViewModel::class.java)
    model.getJokes().observe(this, object : Observer<List<Jokes>>() {
        fun onChanged(@Nullable jokesList: List<Jokes>) {
            adapter = ItemsAdapter()
            recycler.adapter = adapter
        }
    })
}
```

class JokesViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
private var api: Api? = null
var adapter = ItemsAdapter()
private var jokes: List<Jokes> = ArrayList()
private var items: Result? = null

private var jokeList: MutableLiveData<List<Jokes>>? = null

fun getJokes(): LiveData<List<Jokes>> {
    if (jokeList == null) {
        jokeList = MutableLiveData()
        loadItems(5)
    }

    return jokeList as MutableLiveData<List<Jokes>>
}


private fun loadItems(jokeCount: Int?) {
    val call = api?.getItems(jokeCount)

    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Result> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Result>, response: Response<Result>) {
            items = response.body()
            jokes = items!!.value
            items?.let { adapter.setJokes(jokes) }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Result>, t: Throwable) {
            println(t)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fragment `this` is not a lifecycle owner try using `requireActivity()` or `viewLifecycleOwner`
refer [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/0993713cc57869bf62a7627dc06de6f4dd792f76/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/fragment/TodoFragment.kt#L170)

Edit #3
Problem was in importing Observer. This code works fine:

try

```
model.getJokes().observe(requireActivity(), android.arch.lifecycle.Observer{ it -> 
    fun onChanged(@Nullable jokesList: List<Jokes>) {
        // do something
    }
    onChanged(it)
})
```

Otherwise, you should make sure List not null by using List<Jokes!>!

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but the problem is object : Observer<List<Jokes>>()

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using lamdba , or am I missing something

Comment: I don't really understand how it works. I subscribe to the method getJokes() and then what should I specify in the lambda? In fact, I'm not even sure that I write correctly at all

Comment: lambda -> `{ it -> TODO() }` here it will be your `List<Jokes>`

Comment: like this? ```model.getJokes().observe(requireActivity(), { List<Jokes!> ->
            fun onChanged(@Nullable jokesList: List<Jokes>) {
                adapter = ItemsAdapter()
                recycler.adapter = adapter
            }
        })``` but it dose not work

Comment: no, not work. `{ it ->
            fun onChanged(@Nullable jokesList: List<Jokes>) {
                adapter = ItemsAdapter()
                recycler.adapter = adapter
            }
            onChanged(it)
        }` this is underlined. Type mismatch Required:Observer<List<Jokes>!> Found (???) -> Unit

Comment: yes. it is "Type mismatch Required:Observer<List<Jokes>!> Found (???) -> Unit" may be i have no some dependencies?